# Android WebView Mixed Content error for redirect https to http form

Tags: android, web, webview

I have a `WebView` with primary `https` secure connection for payment page. Result of this payment page redirected to my site with `http` non secure connection. when user click on first page, that page reloaded instead open my site and i gave this error message:
`"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/mpayment.mellat?RefId=9CFCC0FAEC3C2752' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint 'http://arameshfereshtegan.com/web-service/verify.php'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.", source: https://bpm.shaparak.ir/pgwchannel/mpayment.mellat?RefId=9CFCC0FAEC3C2752 (347)`

I try 2 way to solve it. first use webviewclient and override `onReceivedSslError` and `handler.proceed()` inside it. second use `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
    }`
but both not working.

Comment: it seems you tried to submit to http from https. But data of form in https will be encrypted. In common flow: https --> https, in server side process result and redirect to http. Mixed content is kind of bad smell.